# Finding other generalized inverses besides the pseudoinverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a $16\times 4$ matrix $A$ of rank $4$. Besides its Moore-Penrose pseudoinverse $A^+$, I'm also interested in other generalized inverses $A^g$ that satisfy $A^gA=I_4$.

Is there a way to get *all* of them (presumably in some analytical form with free variables)?

Are there any *special* inverses? By "special," I mean $A^+$ gives the solution to $Ax=y$ with minimum $\ell_2$ norm, so is there one such $A^g$ that gives the solution with minimum $\ell_0$ norm, for example?

If the answers to the two questions above are both "No," how do I find *any* generalized inverse other than the pseudoinverse?

Comment: Here's a hint: Have you thought about putting $A$ in reduced echelon form? What does that tell you? Can you write that in terms of matrix multiplication?

Comment: Thanks @TedShifrin for the hint! Do you mean expressing the process of transforming $A$ into its reduced row echelon form as matrix multiplication? I know I can use reduced echelon form to find a _square_ matrix's inverse. But can't see other connections between the echelon form and generalized inverse. Thanks!

Comment: You can get *one* left inverse by thinking about the equation $EA=I$, where $E$ is a product of elementary matrices. Notice that once you have *one* left inverse $B$, you get others $B'$ by making sure that every row of $B-B'$ is orthogonal to all the columns of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

All generalized inverses can be written as
$$
A^g = A^+ + U(I_{16}-AA^+),
$$
where $U\in {\mathbb C}^{4\times 16}$ is arbitrary.

Note: $I_{16}-AA^+$ is the orthogonal projection onto the null space of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

Denote by $b_i$ the i-th row of $A^g$ and by $e_i$ the i-th row of $I_4$. Then $b_i A=e_i$. This system of four linear equations is solveable by the rank condition for $A$. Following this procedure gives all possible $A^g$.